# Extensionless URL rewriting in web.config ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with URL mysite.com/mypage.aspx and I want visitors to be redirected to this page if they go to mysite.com/mypage. It is only for this page and I wonder if this is possible to achieve in web.config. I do not have access to any source code, only to web.config (via FTP). I tried to log in to our web hosts control panel to check if there's any settings there I can use but it seems to be down for the moment.

So can I do something like this in web.config (it's ASP.NET 2.0 if that matters)?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/index.htm" mappedUrl="~/default.aspx"/>
 <add url="~/mypage" mappedUrl="~/mypage.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

It works for index.htm but not (obviously) when there's no extension in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do any url routing in code with asp.net 2.0 (only 3.5, 4.0 and you need source code for those).

Do you have access to IIS to [UrlRewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Comment: I'm not sure yet, our web host's control panel is currently offline. I'll have a look as soon as it is up again